# Process substitution over ssh with sudo in Bash shell

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo, process-substitution

What is the proper way to do something like this:

```
diff <( ssh -t myuser@hosta 'sudo httpd -M') <(httpd -M)
```

When I want to compare the output of the 2 commands, the first on a remote host the second local?

Is this the proper method?

Comment: That looks fine. What problems are you having with it?

Comment: No problems per se, I was just wondering if using process substitution had any ramifications in regard to ssh.

Comment: None, `ssh` is just a process, like any other.

Comment: This is exactly the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to set public key base authentication in between both server.
how you can set both server public key base auth:

> NOTE:- Enter all commands on local server

first generate ssh key:

> ssh-keygen

then set that key for authenticate remote server:

> ssh-copy-id -i  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@remote_server_address

after done all this check that public key is working proper or not :

> ssh root@remote_server_address

if no password promt for login, i mean without password if you can login then ssh key is working proper.

now use your command local server :

> diff <( ssh -t myuser@hosta 'sudo echo "test1"') <(echo "test2")

Now your command will show you proper output ...

Comment: The `-t` flag seems to prevent this from working, as of OpenSSH 7.3